# C#: DataGridView cannot be filled correctly for the second time

Tags: c#

The following code works good when the form is load. The problem is here, when I call the method again to fill the Datagridview, the datagridview columns are randomly filled with the data which is returned from DB.

```
public void displayDataInGrid()
{
    try
    {
        if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            connection.Open();
        }
        sda = null;
        sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Product", connection);
        ds = new DataSet();

        sda.Fill(ds, "Product");
        dataGridView1.Columns[2].DataPropertyName = "Pro_Name";
        dataGridView1.Columns[3].DataPropertyName = "Pro_Type";
        dataGridView1.Columns[4].DataPropertyName = "Quantity";
        dataGridView1.Columns[5].DataPropertyName = "Cost_Price";
        dataGridView1.Columns[6].DataPropertyName = "Market_Price";
        dataGridView1.Columns[7].DataPropertyName = "Exp_Date";
        dataGridView1.Columns[8].DataPropertyName = "Bar_Code";
        dataGridView1.Columns[9].DataPropertyName = "Pro_Id";
        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];

        connection.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error\n" + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

Comment: Simply specify the columns in the SQL `"SELECT Id,Pro_Name,Pro_Type,Quantity,Cost_Price,Market_Price,Exp_Date,Bar_Code,Pro_Id FROM Product"`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I solved the problem by creating the datagridview again after every time of calling the above method

Answer (score 0):

Try to put this:

```
' ** CODE **
dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
dataGridView1.Refresh();
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];

connection.Close();
' ** CODE **
```

And if it not runs, specify in SQL query the columns you need to show in the DataGridView.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I solved the problem by creating the datagridview again after every time of calling the above method.